# Difference between gravity right and end

Tags: android, android-layout

I was making a xml file and was applying gravity to make view content to shift it to extreme right side of window but i saw gravity as right and end.So, what is the actual difference between the both and which one to use where.

Comment: Left and right are quite literally that. If, however, you are going to support different conventions for language etc then you need to deal with LTR (left to right) or RTL (right to left) concepts. In the case of LTR the 'left' and 'start' mean the same thing and 'right' and 'end' also the same thing. The reverse is true for RTL where 'right' and 'start' are the same and 'left' and 'end' are the same. In other words, if you want to cater for both LTR and RTL then you should use 'start' and 'end' for positioning certain things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in Arabic, Persian and all rtl (Right-To-Left) Locales, `end` is left but for English and other ltr (Left-To-Right) Locales `end` means right

Answer (score 1):

`Left` and `right` gravities might not work correctly in applications localized for right-to-left languages like Hebrew, Arabic etc. In those languages left and right sides are mirrored to european languages. If you use hardcoded `left` and `right` gravities for some elements of your UI, then they might be misplaced in right-to-left localizations. If you use `begin` and `end`, then Android will map them correctly to `left` or `right` depending on current system language. Thus `begin` for English is equal to `left` and for Hebrew to `right` etc.

If you app has a localization for one of right-to-left languages, then you should always use `begin` and `end`. Otherwise you can safely stay with `left` and `right`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion when we set 
android:orientation="horizontal" in the main layout, then it's better to set gravity of its child as start and end to make it more effective with the layout.
BUT
when other orientations are used then we can use other gravity forms as well.